# Blocking DOM Parsing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, domparser

I have a small problem. I have a table on a HTML page, which is filled by an asynchronous call in JS. There are thousands of elements, and obviously they are filled with classes and all to make them pretty :) .

This is done like so:

```
for(var i  = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.className = "all the pretty css";

    var button = document.createElement("a");
    button.className = "btn so pretty wow";
    td.appendChild(button);

    tableTr.appendChild(td);
}
```

However, this takes a lot of time, and by using `console.time` and `console.timeEnd` I was able to determine that the whole process takes about 100ms of JS execution, which means that the time is actually being queued by DOM parsing. (Am I right?)

So, I was wondering if there is any way to do something like:

```
Dom.stopParsing();

mySuperFunction();
anotherFunction();
thisTimeAsync(
    function(){
        Dom.parse();
);
```

And so, effectively reduce parsing time!

Comment: [Running JS already stops DOM parsing and async functions allow parsing to continue](https://jsfiddle.net/Ld81wufg/) so I guess I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @MikeC I just added a simple demo... I'm guessing that every tableTr (which exists in the dom and is not just a js object) launches a parser, so every iteration of the for would queue parsers...

Comment: 100ms does not seem very bad. Also, I cannot parse the sentence "being queued by DOM parsing". By the way, have you considered using document fragments?

Comment: @torazaburo 100ms of JS execution according to `console.time`, to actually see the page it takes about 10-12 seconds... :/

Comment: javascript queues any async calls that are outside the javascript run engine. Any async calls will not be run until javascript finishes every execution context it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment):

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i  = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.className = "all the pretty css";

    var button = document.createElement("a");
    button.className = "btn so pretty wow";
    td.appendChild(button);

    frag.appendChild(td);
}

tableTr.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: I haven't done one yet, I'll do it and comment it back here!